# Does asdf provide a symbolic link shim to a package's directory?

Tags: unix, asdf-vm

asdf-vm provides symbolic links to a package's currently selected *executable* via /shims, like `.asdf/shims/<package>`.  Does it provide a link to the currently selected package directory (which can be found via `asdf where <package>`)?

If not, could I hack this into the install step of a custom asdf-vm plugin?

If not, can I hack this together myself with some bash/*nix fu (preferably macOS) to create a symbolic link of sorts against a command's output, e.g. `$(asdf where <package>)`? (( this seems.. unlikely as that's kernel stuff but I thought I'd ask! ))

Answer (score 0):

asdf actually doesn't use symbolic links to link the currently selected version of the executables to the shims on the path. The shims themselves have their own resolver logic that they use to determine which version of the real executable and execute it with `exec`.

Shims will be created for all executables in the tools (those you've installed plugins for) you have installed.